# list_schemas() method missing on Boto3 Glue client object

Tags: python, boto3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

So, I think I'm running up against an issue with out of date documentation. According to the documentation here I should be able to use `list_schemas()` to get a list of schemas defined in the Hive Data Catalog: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.list_schemas

However, this method doesn't seem to exist:

```
import boto3

glue = boto3.client('glue')
glue.list_schemas()
```

```
AttributeError: 'Glue' object has no attribute 'list_schemas'
```

Other methods (e.g. `list_crawlers()`) still appear to be present and work just fine. Has this method been moved? Do I need to install some additional boto3 libraries for this to work?

Comment: HIi Adam, Could you please take a look at my answer. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: What is your `boto3` version?

Comment: Looks like it's 1.9.253. I'll give upgrading it a try.

Comment: And looks like updating did the trick. Feel free to post this as the answer, @Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using **old boto3**. **Upgrading** to the newer version solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `session` first, and use the `client` method of the session, then it should work:

```py
import boto3
session = boto3.session.Session()
glue_client = session.client('glue')
schemas_name = glue_client.list_schemas()
```

Comment: Could you please clarify why `session` is required in this case?

Comment: Please read this [doc](https://ben11kehoe.medium.com/boto3-sessions-and-why-you-should-use-them-9b094eb5ca8e) carefully. you'll learn when to use `session`s and when you don't need to. @Marcin

Comment: It doesn't seem to change the outcome in this case though :/